# Trying to install amforth on Leonardo board

Tags: arduino-leonardo, atmega32u4

Just got a Arduino Leonardo (with headers) dropped in my lap this week. I've tried experimenting with the Arduino C++ IDE and find it awkward. I have some previous experience with Forth and would like to try loading amforth directly onto the ATmega32u4 microcontroller.

I found some "how to" information on the web but find it confusing and contradictory. Can anyone point to some easy to follow instructions? I'd greatly appreciate it!

In case it matters, my development box is a Fedora 29 workstation.

Comment: what are `easy to follow instructions`? ..... which information did you find? .....  how was it contradictory?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24969/amforth-on-arduino-uno

Comment: Instructions that make no assumptions about any experience with the board.

Comment: Oh BTW, I have but one Leonardo board and the example "wiring" diagram in the link above show 2 Leonardo boards. I assume that's not necessary to use amforth?